# A simple way to do a read a contract from a json file and interract with it using ethers.js?

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-invocation, ethers.js, abi

I'm using `hardhat` and have deployed some contracts. That's created a directory `deployments` which containes meta data of the deployed smart contracts. Is it called `artifacts`?

Now, via the library **ethers.js**, I want to instantiate those contracts and interract with them. The contracts are on `ronkeby`.

I've able to find small pieces, some in `web3.js` and some in `ethers.js` and it's been confusing.

How to do it?

Here's a part of those contracts from `./deployments/rinkeby/MyContract123.json`

```
    {
      "address": "0x<12345>",
      "abi": [
        {
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "_factory",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "internalType": 
              //.............

      "transactionHash": "0x<some data....>",
      "receipt": {
        //.....
      },
      "args": [
        "0x<some data....>",
        "0x<some data....>"
      ],
      "solcInputHash": "<some data....>",
      "metadata": "....",
      "bytecode": "...",
      "deployedBytecode": "....",
      "devdoc": {
      },
      "userdoc": {
      },
      "storageLayout": {
      }
    }
```

How can I read the ABI of this contract and instantiate it, to be then able to interract with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just importing the json file right in my .ts file and referencing it directly from ethers

Import looks like this

```
import myContract from '../../../artifacts/contracts/MyContract.sol/MyContract.json';
```

Then to create the ethers contract I do

```
contract = new ethers.Contract(
  address,
  myContract.abi,
  provider
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for Hardhat could be the plugin [`@0xweb/hardhat`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins), which generates TypeScript classes encapsulating the [dequanto](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto) library. This library is based on ethers.js and web3js.

When the contracts are compiled, the TypeScript classes are automatically generated. These classes include strongly typed methods for:

- Reading data from the blockchain (call methods)
- Submitting data to the network (submit transactions)
- Listening to events and retrieving strongly typed arguments
- Fetching passed strongly typed logs emitted by the contract

To prepare the development environment:

```bash
$ npm i 0xweb -g
$ 0xweb init --hardhat
$ npx hardhat compile --watch
# compiles sol contracts and listens for changes to recompile
```

Here is an example of reading/writing to an ERC20 contract:

```typescript
import { MyContract123 } from './0xweb/hardhat/MyContract123'
import { HardhatProvider } from '@dequanto/hardhat/HardhatProvider'
import { Web3ClientFactory } from '@dequanto/clients/Web3ClientFactory'

let provider = new HardhatProvider();
let client = await provider.client('localhost');
let contract = new MyContract123('0x...', client);
// or you can deploy directly from code using hardhat signer
let contract = await provider.deployClass(MyContract123, { arguments: [ 1, 'foo' ], client });

// or you can target the mainnet
let client = Web3ClientFactory.get('eth');
let contract = new MyContract123('0x...', client);

// Read, Write, Fetch logs:

let decimals = await contract.decimals();

let account = { address: '0x...' }
let tx = contract.transfer(account, '0x...', 5n ** decimals);
let receipt = await tx.wait();

let transfers = await contract.getPastLogsTransfer();
console.log(transfers);
```